# Appointment Type in iCalendar

Tags: icalendar, lotusscript, lotus

In normal LotusScript you can use the item "AppointmentType" to set: Appointment=0, Anniversary=1, Event=2, Invitation=3, Reminder=4.

I would like to use iCalendar, but I haven't found a way to include the type of an appointment in the format. I experimented with X-LOTUS-APPTTYPE, but without an effect (Appointment stays 4).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know I'm late but have you finally found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the type to be recognised by all calendar apps, then consider use a standard RFC 5545 field - maybe the CATEGORY field https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.2